# iOS, launch screen image same proportional size on different devices without blurring?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, launch-screen

I want have an image on my launch screen which occupies the same amount of the screen on different devices.

At the moment I have a logo which is about the right size on iPhone 4s, but on iPhone 6 Plus it's too small. Obviously these devices are in the same autolayout class.

I know I could use proportional sizing, but this will stretch the images and make them look fuzzy.

Also with it being a launch screen I can't use code for drawing or custom controls.

I guess I need some way to determine different devices in my constraints.

Comment: Normally you would have the image with an appropriate resolution so that it is clear on the largest screen and set constraints so that is scales down on smaller devices

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 couldn't that still look fuzzy ?

Comment: Generally images will still be sharp if their resolution is reduced.  If the image has a high level of detail, such as many fine lines, then it could be adversely impacted by reduction, but unless you are actually rendering an image or somehow photographing at different resolutions you are going to have to resize the image show how; either in an image program or in the launch storyboard

Comment: @Paulw11 should I provide my iPad Pro 12 inch width height from ib inspector (I assume that will be points) as my x1 image asset catalog image?

Answer (score 0):

Add LaunchScreen asset group to your Assets. Then it will be possible to assign custom image for each screen resolution.
[image: LaunchScreen assets]

Comment: This is not the recommended approach as you need to develop specific launch images for each resolution and continue to update it as new devices are released.

Comment: @Paulw11 No, you are wrong. Your approach will not work if image contains photo with recognizable object, because screen proportions different on different devices, and result will be distorted.

Comment: You can't scale independent of aspect ratio; you must retain the aspect ratio.  Whether you resize with constraints or resize in Photoshop the effect is the same; You will either have a different amount of border around the image, or some image will be cropped depending on whether the image is full screen or not.

Comment: Agree. There is additional work for designer, but final result more accurate.